# Unable to remove Mailbox Import Requests

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010

I had 2 large imports which screwed up. While I was trying to work out what was wrong I removed the mailboxes (sorry). I have discovered that the import requests are still there and when I try to remove them I get the following error.

```
corp.dcsgroup.com.au/Corp Users/Administration/Test Acct isn't a mailbox user or mail-enabled user.
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (0:Int32) [Remove-MailboxImportRequest], ManagementObjectNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 70B4CA0,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.RecipientTasks.RemoveMailboxImportRequest
```

I am a bit worried I have messed somethig up permanently. Anyone have any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Did you try to reconnect the mailbox to the AD user account or recreate the mailbox or restore it from the dumpster?

Comment: I am about to reopen this problem. The second failed request never timed out. I have tried reconnecting it to a mailbox but I have to deal with "Failed to communicate with the mailbox database" message when trying to remove.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to reconnect the mailboxes didn't work. The shell would give me an error claiming it couldn't connect to the mailbox database. Leaving it for a few days made the mailbox information drop from the mailbox import request; it was then I was able to remove the request.